# PHP regex format for address

Tags: php, preg-match

I have used the given regex format for address

```
$address='2/12, 1st street, ch-90';
(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s #,-.]+$/i', $address))
```

pls suggest me to add the `forward slash` in pregmatch which matches the above address. Thanks

Comment: Two ways are possible: 1) choose an other pattern delimiter 2) escape the slash with a backslash. Note that you should also escape the hyphen in the character class since it defines a range between the comma and the dot (but it's actually not a problem since the comma, the hyphen and the dot are consecutive in the ascii table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this hope this will help you...

You should add `\/` to character classes to match `/` and you must add `-` at the end of character class.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$address='2/12, 1st street, ch-90';
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\/\s #,.-]+$/i', $address,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2/12, 1st street, ch-90
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to offer some regex pattern advice, some postal address handling cautions, and some output advice:

**Pattern advice**:

If you are going to use the `i` flag at the end of your pattern expression, then you don't need to type out both `a-z` and `A-Z` in your character list -- just pick one range.

Unless you are expecting any `\r` `\n` `\t` `\f` `\v` whitespace characters, you should only be using a space () in your character list.

I'll assume that you have considered the likely symbols that you will encounter in your project and by adding an escaped slash (`\/`), you will at least be able to return a `true` result from `preg_match()` for your input string (`$address`).

**Postal address handling cautions**:

Handling address strings can turn into a real rabbits hole.  The best thing to do is establish some rigid guidelines (if you have the power to do so) which limit the format and characters that will exist in a valid address.  If you have no control over the input strings, then it is probable that you will need to expand your regex pattern to include more symbols.  This topic will require a varying about of research depending on the depth and complexity of your project.

**Outputting advice**:

If you just want a pass-fail condition, don't declare the 3rd parameter in `preg_match()`:

```
$address='2/12", 1st street, @ch-90';  // <-- I added invalid symbols to your string

if(preg_match('/^[a-z\d \/#,.-]+$/i',$address)){
    echo "Address is valid";
    // do whatever is next and use unchanged $address
}else{
    echo "Address contains invalid character(s)";  // <-- this one will be shown
    // do whatever is next and use unchanged $address
}
```

If you want to identify the failing character(s), use `preg_match_all()`, change pattern, and declare the 3rd parameter.  This can provide a better user experience because you are explaining what is causing the address value to be invalid.  That said, if you are using this pattern to protect your site from malicious attacks then, of course, you don't want to be providing these clues.  This is the `preg_match_all()` method:

```
if(preg_match_all('/[^a-z\d \/#,.-]/',$address,$m)){
    echo "Address deemed invalid because of: ",implode("",$m[0]);  // or however you want to display it
    // do whatever is next
}else{
    echo "Address is valid";
    // do whatever is next
}
```